# Unity: Platform Spawner

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been working on endless platform spawner but I don't know how to use decimal number in code. I've been trying to use `private double` or `private decimal` but I didn't figure it out. Here is my code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlatformManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject[] _platformPrefabs;
    [SerializeField]
    private int _zedOffset;
    private int _yOffset;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; 1 < _platformPrefabs.Length; i++)
        {
            global::System.Object value = Instantiate(_platformPrefabs[i], new Vector3(0, i * -24.8, i * -30), Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0));
            _zedOffset += -30;
            _yOffset += -24.8;
        }
    }

    public void RecyclePlatform(GameObject platform)
    {
        platform.transform.position = new Vector3(0, _yOffset, _zedOffset);
        _zedOffset += -30;
        _yOffset += -24.8;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you storing vector components into `int`, `float`, `double` anyway?  Just use `Vector3`, it makes math a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use floats

private float _myFloat;

_myFloat = 1.23f;

Comment: private float _yOffset = 24.8f; like that?

Comment: yes like that should work

Comment: I get error: cannot convert from 'double' to 'float'

Comment: you must have set the _yOffset to a different data type than float.

Comment: I still dont understand.

Comment: Why are you storing vector components into `int`, `float`, `double` anyway?  Just use `Vector3`, it makes math a whole lot easier.